# "No space left on device" with cgroups v2 writing empty string to `cpuset.cpus`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

I'm using Linux 5.11 in the unified cgroups v2 configuration.

Following [cgroups-v2.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst), I'm trying to reset cpuset assignment of a non-root cgroup (to make it inherit the parent's cpuset). According to the doc, this can be achieved by writing an empty value into `cpuset.cpus` of a cgroup:

```
Cpuset Interface Files
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  cpuset.cpus

    <...>

    An empty value indicates that the cgroup is using the same
    setting as the nearest cgroup ancestor with a non-empty
    "cpuset.cpus" or all the available CPUs if none is found.
```

However, this does not work:

```
# pwd
/sys/fs/cgroup/machine.slice/systemd-nspawn@stratofortress.service

# cat cpuset.cpus
0-31

# echo "" > cpuset.cpus
echo: write error: no space left on device
```

What am I doing wrong?